# ASP.net MVC or Knockout.JS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

this may be a newbie question. I originally wrote a prototype in MVVM and WPF. The client wants to use MVC and jQuery. Not an issue. I wrote a lot of business logic in the VIEWMODEL.

If I use knockout.js is it just a matter of using the javascript library and creating new bindings?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Your ViewModels should be dumb objects with no business logic, only properties and validation annotations. Business logic should be contained to it's own tier.

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange I guess I think that the model is what is dumb w/o business long and 'only annotations' and the view model as the glue to the view.

Comment: In reality, the preferred methodology is the opposite what what you have done. The ViewModel is used only by the UI, and should reflect the UIs data needs. The UI and ViewModel should contain no business logic. Your Business Logic Layer should contain the logic. The controller acts as the glue that passes the entity data (model) to a ViewModel and on to the UI. The same goes for data access, the UI, ViewModels or BLL should not contain data access code. What you have is going against the patterns of good design and maintainability. That's obvious now that you have to change and can't easily

Comment: @kenny no, model should not be dumb. It's considered an anti-pattern: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: MVC is a pattern, are you referring to asp.net mvc the .net web framework?

Comment: Knockout is a javascript framework that help you apply the mvvm pattern to your application IN THE CLIENT SIDE, you can use Knockout in ASP.net MVC, plain html, pylons, etc, etc... I guess that you can do a little research for some project to achieve the MVVM pattern in the server (asp.net side) doing some modifications to asp.net webforms or mvc.

Comment: There is [Knockout MVC](http://knockoutmvc.com) - special knockout.js-wrapper for ASP.NET MVC. Perhaps it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are completely different technologies for different purposes. Knockout.JS is a powerful client side scripting with the usage of mvvm patter, while MVC is a architectural pattern to build real stateless web applications with capabilities to tune up as needed.

There might be a misconception that MVC pattern works only in ASP.NET MVC framework. Other web programming languages also use it or have potential to implement this pattern. However, in .NET it has some extra really powerful extensions and an active community to learn it quick and practice fearlessly.

Comment: **Basically** it's a short and concise summary.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use both? I'm using knockout and mvvm

Comment: Perhaps you mean you're using knockout and MVC?